# Contextmenu not getting closed

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu

I need to close the contextmenu when the user clicks outside the menu window. How can I implement it? In some places, I have seen that contextmenu gets closed when user clicks outside the window. Or is there any other way to close the contextmenu. Please help..thanks.my code is here

```
selectedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selected_imageview);
    registerForContextMenu(selectedImageView);
}
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Post Image");
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextmenu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
      switch (item.getItemId())
      {
          case R.id.take_photo:
              Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mag.class);
              this.startActivity(intent);
              break;
          case R.id.choose_gallery:
              Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Mag1.class);
              this.startActivity(intent2);
              break;

          case R.id.share_cancel:
              Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, Mag2.class);
              this.startActivity(intent3);
              break;
          default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
      }
      return true;
    }
```

Comment: the selectedimageview in above code is the image selected from a galleryview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
public static final int take_photo= Menu.FIRST;
public static final int choose_gallery= Menu.FIRST+1;
public static final int share_cancel= Menu.FIRST+2;


@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {     

    menu.add(0,take_photo, 0, "take_photo");

    menu.add(0, choose_gallery, 0, "choose_gallery");  

    menu.add(0, share_cancel, 0, "share_cancel");  
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {        ;
    onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    return true;
}

  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

   switch (item.getItemId())
  {
      case R.id.take_photo:
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mag.class);
          this.startActivity(intent);
          break;
      case R.id.choose_gallery:
          Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Mag1.class);
          this.startActivity(intent2);
          break;

      case R.id.share_cancel:
          Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, Mag2.class);
          this.startActivity(intent3);
          break;
      default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
  }
  return true;

}
```

Comment: thanks for the help..but, still it remains the same. On clicking any of the option, it works fine and gets closed itself. But what if the user doesn't want to select any of the option? thats my problem here

Comment: can you be more specific? will it make automatic closing of that window? whre should I put sleep()?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to implement any other code for what you require.

Android provide automatically closing of `menu window` when you click outside of its block

Comment: i tried clicking outside..but its not getting closed. I am trying on emulator. Do i need to check the same in android device?

Comment: no need of checking in device.it will close. i think there is some problem with your R.menu.contextmenu. try creating menu items manually as @nagarjunareddy said

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't provide this behavior on pre-ics versions, so have to write extra code for getting this done.